# Deploy django on CPanel

Tags: python, django, cpanel

I have finished the development of my application and I'm ready to deploy. I'm renting a host with CPanel. The current setup does not contain modules neither for python nor django. What do you believe it is better to do. Could I install python and django from the command line and by pass the cPanel interface?

If anyone knows about cPanel plugins for django and have any experience, I'm glad to hear!

Thank you!

Comment: I once had a server with cPanel/WHM, I could tell you that doing it from the command line is better because the cPanel interface is too magical, it's best to have control on what and how you install the packages. Also I don't know if it's fixed but I had to disable the ForkBomb protection in order for the WSGI server to work because of the amount of resources it uses... ironic...

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

http://server-support.co/blog/sysadmin/django-on-cpanel-server-for-shared-web-hosting/

1.) Download and extract Django from http://pypi.python.org/simple/django/ into /usr/src

2.) run python setup.py install